# How to display image when reading from a text file using Perl CGI?

Tags: perl, cgi

[image: Latest Table/Output]

This is the first row from the text file that contains the image `0001|Yamaha FS700S|Acoustic Guitar|$200.00|<img src=“/cgi-bin/asst5/asst5_img/Yamaha_FS700S.jpg"/>`

The source code for the text file is `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/cgi-bin/asst5`

This is the CGI script to read the file and display in a table

```
use CGI qw(:standard);
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);
use strict;
use warnings;
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";

 print "<TABLE BORDER>\n";
 print "<TR><TH>SKU Code<TH>Name<TH>Description<TH>Price<TH>Photos"; 
open my $order_fh, '<', 'inventory.txt' or die "Error opening file, $!";

while(<$order_fh>) {
  print "<TR>\n";
  print '<TD>' . join('</TD><TD>', split /\|/) . "</TD>\n";
  print "</TR>\n";
}

close $order_fh;
 print "</TABLE>";
```

Updated Error Log:

```
 [Fri Nov 04 10:09:23.102929 2016] [cgi:error] [pid 3814] [client ::1:50571] 
 AH02811: script not found or unable to stat: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/cgi-bin/asst5/\xc3\xa2\xe2\x82\xac\xc5\x93, referer: http://localhost/cgi-bin/asst5/showmdse.cgi
```

Comment: The text record that you've just added from the data file is different to the text in the image. Which is the correct version?

Comment: it should be the second one

Comment: So the image is wrong? To be honest, that doesn't seem likely looking at the error log.

Comment: @DaveCross The table is the same result with both. I was just using the first row of items from the text file as an example of how the photo on the table doesnt work.

Comment: But is the error message the same too? I bet it isn't.

Comment: My point is that the long URL (that starts '/Applications/...') is clearly wrong. That will generate the error message that you've posted in your question. But the shorter URL (that starts '/cgi-bin/...') will almost certainly generate a different error message (probably the one discussed in my answer below). It would be helpful to see that error message as well. It would also be helpful to see the actual data file. Can you put it online and provide a link?

Comment: @DaveCross Thank you for taking the time and helping out. I updated the error log, the directory of the image in the text file. The latest table graphic is the same as before

Comment: Right. Two things. Firstly, this error was generated by the older, longer, incorrect URL in your data file. I can tell that because the error message includes the URL of the script it's trying to execute. So, no, that's almost certainly not generated by a data file containing the shorter URL. Secondly, you have broken the image link again. Also, have you tried the solution I mentioned in my answer below? Given the random nature of your replies, I'm starting.to think I should give up here for the sake of my sanity. And perhaps you should employ a programmer.

Comment: Look, this is really simple. 1/ Don't store your images in the CGI directory. 2/ Work out what the URL is for the directory where you store the images. 3/ Put that URL in your data file.

Comment: Do you understand the difference between a URL and a file path? That's pretty crucial.

Comment: @DaveCross Please explain, what is this? `file:///Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/cgi-bin/asst5/asst5_img/Yamaha_FG700S.jpg`. Isn't this the image URL and directory?

Comment: @DaveCross this is the one for the text file `file:///Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/cgi-bin/asst5/inventory.txt`. I just need to put that image in this txt file. Is using `<img src=“"/>` in the text file the right way of doing it?

Comment: It's a [file URL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme). That's a URL-compatible way to identify files on your local computer. File URLs shouldn't be used in web applications as they won't work for anyone connecting remotely to your web server. Why are you ignoring all of my advice and coming up with your own ridiculous solutions to the problem?

Comment: @DaveCross I'm sorry, still very new to this. Where do you suggest I put the images? This is for a project and I need to put them in a separate folder.

Comment: I think your document root is `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/`. Create a new directory there called `images`. Put your images in there. Then your data file should contain something like `<img src=“/images/Yamaha_FS700S.jpg"/>`.

Comment: @DaveCross I put the image folder in `xamppfiles` because putting it in Applications will show `Error 404 The requested URL was not found on this server.` when I right clicked on the broken image. Tried `<img src=“/xamppfiles/asst5_img/Yamaha_FS700S.jpg"/>
` and `<img src=“/asst5_img/Yamaha_FS700S.jpg"/>`. The image still won't show

Comment: Putting it in `xamppfiles` was what I suggested. Why don't you read my comments more carefully? The `xamppfiles` directory is (probably) your document root, so it won't be part of the URL. I'd expect `/asst5_img/Yamaha_FS700S.jpg` to be right though. But I don't know how your XAMPP installation is configured. Where is your main `index.html` file?

Comment: Is there a directory called `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs`? You might need to put your image directory inside there.

Comment: @DaveCross I put the images folder in htdocs and used `0001|Yamaha FS700S|Acoustic Guitar|$200.00|<img src=“/htdocs/asst5_img/Yamaha_FS700S.jpg"/>` . That doesn't work either with the same error as earlier.

Comment: Did you create `htdocs` or did it already exist? If it already existed, then the URL you probably want is `/asst5_img/Yamaha_FS700S.jpg`. Is there no-one there who knows how web servers work?

Comment: It was already there. I am using Apache. I tried that too, doesn't work

Comment: What happens if you right-click on the broken image and select "view image"? And I assume you're watching the error logs carefully through all of this. What is that saying?

Comment: It takes me to the `Error 404 The requested URL was not found on this server`.  Error log says `[Fri Nov 04 12:54:51.576679 2016] [cgi:error] [pid 946] [client ::1:52358] AH02811: script not found or unable to stat: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/cgi-bin/asst5/\xc3\xa2\xe2\x82\xac\xc5\x9b, referer: http://localhost/cgi-bin/asst5/showmdse.cgi`

Comment: When you "view image", what URL appears in the location bar? Does it have those weird hex characters on the end?

Comment: And wait! Why does the error log still say it's looking in cgi-bin? You've moved the images to htdocs and (hopefully) edited the data file. Are you editing the correct copy of the data file - the one that the CGI program is actually using?

Comment: The CGI script and text file are in the cgi-bin and I have to keep them there. The image file doesn't belong there like you said earlier.

Comment: **When you "view image", what URL appears in the location bar?**

Comment: What happens when you type `http://localhost/asst5_img/Yamaha_FS700S.jpg` in your location bar?

Answer (score 3):

I don't understand why people think it's a good idea to post images of text in Stack Overflow questions. If you have text, then include it in your question as text.

Have you looked in the web server error log? That will almost certainly give you a big clue to what is going wrong here. But here's my hunch...

Your image file is in your CGI directory. Your web server is configured to treat any file in your web directory as a executable file. So when your web server gets a request for a resource in the CGI directory, it doesn't just serve the file, it executes the file and passes whatever the program returns back to the browser.

So here's what happens. Your user requests the web page. Your CGI program is executed and the HTML is returned to the browser. That HTML includes an image tag. When the browser parses the HTML, it finds the image tag and that generates another request to the web server. This request asks for the iamge file from the CGI directory. The web server tries to execute the image file - and that doesn't work. So the web server returns a 500 error and the browser displays the "broken image" icon.

I bet that if you look in the web server error log, you'll see a message about a "failure to execute" the image file.

The solution is to move your images out of the CGI directory into the web server directories that contain static files. You'll need to adjust the URL in the data file too.

I'm sad to see that you still haven't changed the mid-90s HTML in your program or switched to using a templating system.

**Update:** Oh, and there's another potential error here (which might be masking the error I discussed above). The `src` attribute for your image tag is wrong. I bet that "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/cgi-bin/asst5/asst5_img" is a file path and not a URL. I'm not sure how XAMPP is configured, but I bet the URL you really want is "/cgi-bin/asst5/asst5_img".

That will give you a "404 file not found" error in your error log.

**Update2:** So you've added the text from the error log and, as predicted, that's a "file not found" error (although I'm not entirely sure where those hex characters are coming from).

Comment: I don't understand why those same people can't even post the image that they have obviously uploaded with the dialogue which results in markdown that _includes the image_ in the post. Do they all remove the `[!...][1]` part from `[![text][1]][1]` because it looks so weird and they think it's wrong? If they worry that much then why would they try to post an image in the first place...?

Comment: I once posted an image of the solution as a response, so the OP at least had to re-type it. That was mean, but I enjoyed it so much as a payback. :-)